# SQL Tabs create table running forever

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I just installed SQL tabs on a new laptop and am trying to create a new table for a personal project. When I run this code it just runs/renders forever, where previously on the other machines I've used it renders in seconds.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
    user_id serial,
    user_email varchar,
    user_given_name varchar,
    user_surname varchar,
    image_url varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
```

Perhaps I should include that I am using Heroku.com for my URI. I added `?ssl=true` to the end of the URI.

Answer (score 0):

good afternoon. there is no closing bracket in your example

Comment: Thanks, yeah I missed that part when I pasted in my code. I am fairly new and likely to make mistakes like this for now :P.

That said, I don't believe that was the issue with SQL tabs.